# Ring shape android as TextView background

Tags: android, textview, shapes

I want to dynamically create TextViews inside a circle background. I used this but top and bottom edges of the ring shape gets cut off.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="ring">
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/blue_new"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

I use this as the background for my TextView

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_keyword"
  />
```

Ring shape background gets cutoff. What am I doing wrong? Any clue will be appreciated.

I want to achieve something like this but Radius should be text size

[image]

Comment: What is the exact effect you are trying to achieve by setting a ring as a background of `TextView`? Can you provide with some illustration of it?

Comment: i edited my question in order to illustrate the effect. Also I want to add that TextView will be dynamically created so there is no fixed size in ring

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval">
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/red" android:width="2dip"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I have tried this, already, but this will result in an oval instead of circle. I finally made a custom view and draw the shape via canvas. It's more complex but it worked. Thanks for solution, 'though